# How do you set Content-Encoding for an upload to AWS S3 using AWSSDK.S3 package in .NET?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, awss3transferutility

Task: Upload an already-compressed file to an Amazon AWS S3 bucket using the AWSSDK.S3 package in .NET Core, and set the Content-Encoding header to "gzip".

I have an S3 bucket that I am trying to upload to.  I'm using an IO stream for the data, but there's no way to set the item's Content-Encoding during the upload process.  This is the header I want to set that the item will have when served up by the S3 service (it is not the Content-Encoding for the upload itself).

I am using the TransferUtility and TransferUtilityUploadRequest objects.  Whereas you can set Content-Type just fine (see below), there is no property to set Content-Encoding.  If you use the Metadata.Add function, it will automatically rewrite Content-Encoding to a custom "x-amz-meta-content-encoding" key, which is of course useless.

From what I understand you can't set the Metadata in S3 after the fact except by copying the object, or doing it yourself manually (this is a no-go for me, too many files).  With copying the object, I'm not sure I'd be able to set the metadata anyway.

```
            var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreden‌​tials, bucketRegion);
            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

            byte[] compressedDataArray = <some compressed data>;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(compressedDataArray)) {
                var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                    Key = fileKey + ".gz",
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                    InputStream = memoryStream,
                    AutoCloseStream = true
                };
                fileTransferUtilityRequest.Metadata.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
            }
```

It will upload to a the new file in S3, but will not have Content-Encoding header set.

Please help, anyone! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

okay what seems to work is to set the ContentEncoding on the Headers collection for the request:

```
fileTransferUtilityRequest.Headers.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
```